# Controller issues in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova, controller

I have a controller that does a simple thing.. It opens up the url that is being passed using Phonegap inapp browser. It was working but no longer working!

```
.controller('JobDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Job', 'Profile',function ($scope, $routeParams, Job,Profile) {
  $scope.job = Job.get({jobId: $routeParams.jobId});
  $scope.url=$scope.job.url;
  $scope.read($scope.url);                           

  //Defining read function to open inapp browser
  $scope.read =function(url){
         console.log("myurl"+url);
         var ref = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes,toolbar=yes');
         ref.addEventListener('exit', function() {  });
   };
```

When I call this function it fails. It does not print anything in the console. Please help.

Thanks

JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the function before calling it... Try this

```
.controller('JobDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Job', 'Profile',function ($scope, $routeParams, Job,Profile) {

  //Defining read function to open inapp browser
  $scope.read =function(url){
  ......
 };

 $scope.read($scope.url); //<<--- Invoke read after defining it.
```

Comment: Now I know what I had changed. I had moved things around.